# Incremental extract task on airflow

Tags: python, airflow, etl

I've been trying to learn about airflow. I would like to know what would be the best way to attack the problem below? I have an extract step that needs to be run several times before it reach the last page. I will know that it is the last page by the return of endpoint. I can't change the batch size and I need follow the order of pages to recover the items. However, I would like to carry out the load as I receive the data items.

I thought of the code below which obviously results in a cycle. I was thinking of letting the dag be rescheduled every minute, but I believe this would generate a lot of hits on the same page because I would sent the same token... Also, if I reschedule every minute I will need another dag to trigger this one weekly and a way to define that should be not run it again, correct?

```
@task(do_xcom_push=False, multiple_outputs=True)
def transform(): pass
@task(do_xcom_push=False, multiple_outputs=True)
def load(): pass

previous='{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="extract",key="return_value") }}'
extract = PythonVirtualenvOperator(task_id='extract', python_callable=OaiPmhCallable,op_kwargs={'conn_id': 'lume_oai_conn_id', 'previous': previous}, requirements=['sickle'])                
has_next = ShortCircuitOperator(task_id='has_next', python_callable=OaiPmhHasNextCallable, op_kwargs={ 'previous': previous })
transform = transform()
load = load()

extract >> transform >> load
load >> has_next >> extract
```

Making this issue clearer, I can't understand the way to do this pipeline in incremental mode with multiple batches until the final page is reached. Can someone give an example similar to attack this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to build the pagination into the custom operator and then send it all as one big batch to the next task once it's done getting all the data from the API (I'm assuming that's what you're trying to do). You can't kick off downstream processing while you're still paginating through the results that the API returns, but basically what you'd want is to define that custom PythonOperator like:

```
def custom_operator_callable(timeout=3600):
   # Could do the timeout in the operator
   # But I don't trust like that
   more_results = True
   end_time = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=3600)
   all_results = []
   offset = 0
   while (datetime.now() > end_time) and more_results:
       this_batch = get_api_results(offset=offset)
       all_results.append(this_batch["data"])
       more_results = this_batch["has_more_results"] 
       offset += this_batch["offset"]
   return all_results
```

Obviously implement the pagination better, but that's the general pattern. There may even be a library that can handle the pagination for you. You just need the python operator that hits the API to handle it all and not terminate until it's gotten all the data.